# Multiple 4-20ma sensors cabling

Tags: analog, plc

I am planning on wiring 8 x 4-20ma 2 wire sensors to a PLC.

I would like to know if I need an individual 2 core shielded cable for every sensor or, if I can simply run all the sensors in a single multicore shielded cable (16 core).

Kind regards
Pablo

Comment: Usually the sensors are displaced. Each sensor has a cable gland or connector, so I don't quite understand how would you wire a 16 core cable to a sensor.

Comment: you are correct, the sensors are distanced from each other by a few meters, but there is a central junction box where they run to. This will be where the multicore cable will be connected to the 2 core cables running to each sensor .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be okay, especially for typical narrow bandwidth signals, though I'd be a bit more cautious if they are HART or one of the other multifarious fieldbuses.

Answer (score 3):

Being current driven and feeding a low impedance current shunt - typically 250 Ω to give 5 V at 20 mA - it should be quite immune to noise. You're also providing separate + supplies to each sensor so you won't see any changes in supply voltage if one or more sensors make step changes in current.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point reading analog signals by current is to avoid the EMI caused within cables. 4-20mA signal current loops are practically immune to EMI and stacking them into a single cable should not present any issue. You would need to have a very high frequency signal in order for the issue to become present due to long lengths of cable introducing capacitive coupling between signals which would result in differential mode noise. I believe this is nonexistent in industrial automation sensor applications. This is assuming that they don't use HART protocol, which even then I believe that the 1200Hz and 2200Hz frequencies wouldn't be high enough to introduce any noise.

According to this [article](https://www.dataforth.com/4-20mA-transmitter.aspx), with a 250Ω input the common mode noise introduced to a 4-20mA circuit would be reduced to a factor of more than a 1000 which is huge.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I could not find this info anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an economical question than one of signal integrity. Generally speaking, nobody in industry would hesitate to use a multi-pair cable in this application if it was the economical solution (based on location, routing, marshalling junction box cost, etc.). These cables are often provided with individually-shielded pairs, and an overall shield under the the jacket, each with its own drain wire.

Answer (score 0):

Yes do it, it will be fine. As mentioned above, do not share grounds or voltage sources. Ensuring clean dedicated paths to ground will stop strange reflections and conducted electromagnetic interference problems. Also as mentioned above current "transimpedance" signals are particularly robust to radiated EMI. And to a fair amount of conducted EMI as well.